# Arc & Circle in jsdraw2d

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the following problem in `jsdraw2d` and please advise if it is a bug or it has to do with my understanding.

1. I am trying to fill an Arc.
2. Width = 100,  Height = 100, Start Angle = 0, Swap Angle = 130
3. I fills the Arc perfectly.
4. As I keep on increasing the Swap Angle till 134, it is OK but
5. As and when I change the Swap Angle to 135, it takes a big jump.

In the code also I have seen that there is a check for 135 degree:

`(if((eaD<=45 && eaD>=0) || (eaD>=135 && eaD<=225) || (eaD>=315 && eaD<=360)))`

Is it intentional? If so then why?

Is there a more stable version?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used jsdraw2d, and I wouldn't based on how they present it, on their site.

What I would use, is [RapaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). It's a very mature library, from an extremely skilled developers, that I have used before and know works well.